# Conversion of string to stack-int-value, when is negative, results in strange value

Tags: c++

I'm trying to convert my string of numbers in a stack, but I don't understand why when the number is negative, the first element is always `-3`.

```
void Soma::StrToInt(char str1[], char str2[]) {
    for (int i = 0; str1[i] != '\0'; i++) {
        if (str1[0] == '-') {              //if is negative
            negative1 = true;
        }
        p1.push(str1[i] - '0');
        cout << p1.top() << endl;//Always showing the first element == -3
    }

    for (int i = 0; str2[i] != '\0'; i++) {
        if (str1[0] == '-') {
            negative2 = true;
        }
        p2.push(str2[i] - '0');
    }
}
```

The full code is too big to post here, the problem is why this `-3` value appears, when my string is negative, like `-500`, `-9514897654654` or any negative number.

Minimal version:

```
int main() {
    char str1[] = { '-','4','0','0' };
    stack<int> p1;

    for (int i = 0; str1[i] != '\0'; i++) {
        p1.push(str1[i] - '0');
        cout << p1.top() << endl;
        p1.pop();
    }
}
```

Comment: _"The full code is to big"_ reduce it to a [MCVE] that reproduces your problem then.

Comment: Have you tried a debugger?

Comment: ok, a moment...

Comment: Also, do you know what `'-' - '0'` computes to?

Comment: @FilipiMaciel  `p1.push(str1[i] - '0');` you are using this statement unconditionally, so you effectively will do `p1.push('-' - '0');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here is that `p1.push(str1[i] - '0');` is trying to subtract `'0'` from `'-'` if the string holds a negative number since you always start with `i = 0`.  What you need to do is check if the string is negative or not before the loop and then depending on that check start at `0` or `1`.  You could have something like

```
void Soma::StrToInt(char str1[], char str2[]){
    int start = 0;
    if(str1[0] == '-'){              //if is negative
        negative1 = true;
        start = 1;
    }
    for(int i=start; str1[i]!='\0'; i++)
    //...
}
```

Now if the string is negative you will skip the `'-'` in the string and just push the numbers.

Comment: Ok, i'll try this. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you, now i understand.

Comment: @FilipiMaciel No problem.  Glad to help